# Returning a quantity of 1 for specific items on an invoice with Freemarker

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker in NetSuite's Advanced PDF/HTML templates to generate an Invoice. For specific item types, I want to display "1" instead of the actual quantity on the Invoice. This is based on the item category drop down field selection of "Services". My current attempt is below.

```
<#if record.custitem_item_category?string?contains("Services")>
<td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">1</td>
<#else>
<td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
</#if>
```

I tried validating the initial #if statement with ?has_content but it just skipped to the #else statement so think I've missed something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the field name `custitem_xx` it sounds like you are trying to access a Custom Item Field. Two problems here. Firstly you need to read the value from each line (i.e. it should be `item.item.custitem_item_category` not `record.custitem_item_category`. But additionally (unless it's been recently fixed), doing so in NetSuite just returns the value from the first line of the sublist for every single line item.

What you need to do is create a Custom Transaction Line Field and source in the value from the item, which you would then access like `item.custcol_item_category`.

[When you create the custom field, uncheck Store Value to make sure it is always sourcing in the latest value, and also make sure it is checked under Screen Fields on the form to display in the UI - otherwise it is not available to your template either. If you do want to hide it in the UI, you can just blank out the label.]

Comment: This solved the issue. You were correct about the item.item.custitem_item_category simply returning the value of the first line in the sublist, so created the Custom Transaction Line Field and sourced as described.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement looks correct, which means that `record.custitem_item_category?string?contains("Services")` is not returning the value you think it is. Typically you would only use `?string` on a number to convert it to a string, if it is already a string, this is unnecessary.

Try just printing out `${record.custitem_item_category}` on each line and see what results you get. If some of them contain 'Service' then you should be fine with `record.custitem_item_category?contains("Services")` in your if statement.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried printing out the ${record.custitem_item_category} and got nothing, so looks like that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: Like michoel mentioned, is this field a body field on the Sales Order, or is it an item field on the line items? If it's a line field you should see something like `<#list record.item as item>` that starts your item list. Then to access fields on the item list you would use `${item.description}` inside of the list, or in your case `${item.item.custitem_item_category}` (this is how you can get fields from the item record).

Answer (score 0):

Below thing works...

<#if item.colname=="Package">   (here you can set 1)

<#elseif item.colname=="Discount"/>   (here you can set 2)

<#else>